# Thymeleaf write Placeholder name instead of null

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I don't know if this has already been discussed here, but i have a question.
Is is possible in Thymeleaf to print the Variable name instead of null if it's not there.

For example, in Velocity if i have ${variable1} and i dont set the variable1, it just prints ${variable1}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by `Extending Thymeleaf` features. I suppose you are thinking of this because of debug reasons, so simply do this:

```
<p th:text="${var}">var</p>
```

If the variable does not exist, the text inside is printed.